# implementing a try/catch block

Tags: java, try-catch

So I am working on a guessing number game that uses a try/catch block to catch (this is homework). If the user enters a non-integer value or a number that is below or above the given range (in this case 1-10).

But I am having issues understanding/properly placing the try catch block I read on how it works but when I try to implement it into my simple code it just seems to be ignored.

Here is the code

```
//import statements
import java.util.*;     //for scanner class


// class beginning
class  Guess {
    public static void main(String[] args ) { 
        //Declare variables area

        int secretNumber, guess;

        secretNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);           

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


        // beginning message to user to explain the program
        System.out.println("Welcome to my guess a number program!");
        System.out.println("Please enter in a number to begin guess what the secret number is(1-10): ");   

        //Collect inputs from user or read in data here

        System.out.println("Enter a guess (1-10): ");
        try {
            guess = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (guess < 1 || guess > 10){
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            guess= keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Not a valid integer");
        }
        //Echo input values back to user here



        //main code and calculations to do
        do {

            if (guess < 1 || guess > 10) {
                System.out.println("Your guess is not in the corre try again.");
                guess = keyboard.nextInt();
            }
            if (guess == secretNumber) {
                System.out.println("Your guess is correct. Congratulations!");
                guess = keyboard.nextInt();
            } else if (guess < secretNumber) {
                System.out
                        .println("Your guess is smaller than the secret number.");
                guess = keyboard.nextInt();
            } else if (guess > secretNumber) {
                System.out
                        .println("Your guess is greater than the secret number.");
                guess = keyboard.nextInt();
            }
        } while (guess != secretNumber);


        //End program message
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Hope you enjoyed using this program!");
    }// end main method 


}// end class
```

It doesn't display `"Your guess is correct. Congratulations!"` when you guess the right number.

Am I implementing the try catch block correctly? If not how do I and can it be explained so I can do the second one where it catches the float, string and anything not a int.

what it does do

- it correctly randomizes from 1-10
- the program does check to see if it is within the given range

**EDIT** 
below is the updated code my only issue I have with it now is that I can't figure out how to apply another catch if a user just hits enter without entering anything I assume I'd need to take the input from user turn it into a string then compare?

```
    //import statements
import java.util.*;     //for scanner class


 // class beginning
public class Guess {
public static void main(String[] args ) {
    //Declare variables area
    int guess, secretNumber =  (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1), lowGuess,highGuess;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // beginning message to user to explain the program
    System.out.println("Welcome to my guessing number program!");
    System.out.println("Please enter in a number to start guessing(enter in a number between 1-10): ");

    //main code and calculations to do
    guess = 0;
    lowGuess = 0;
    highGuess = 11;
    do {
        try {
            guess = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (guess < 1 || guess >10){
                System.out.println("Your guess is not in the correct range try again.");
            }
            else if(guess == secretNumber){
                System.out.println("Your guess is correct. Congratulations!");
            }
            else if(guess < secretNumber && guess <= lowGuess){
                System.out.println("The number you entered is either the same entered or lower please re-enter");
            }
            else if (guess < secretNumber && guess > lowGuess){
                lowGuess = guess;
                System.out.println("Your guess is smaller than the secret number.");
            }
            else if ( guess > secretNumber && guess >= highGuess ){
                System.out.println("The number you entered is either the same entered or higher please re-enter");
            }
            else if (guess > secretNumber && guess < highGuess){
                highGuess = guess;
                System.out.println("Your guess is greater than the secret number.");
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Not a valid input please re-enter");
            keyboard.next();
            guess = 0;
        }
    } while (guess != secretNumber);

    //End program message
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Hope you enjoyed using this program!");
}// end main method


}// end class
```

Comment: You're only catching the exception the first time, and missing all the other `nextInt()`. I suggest you do `nextInt()` only once inside the do/while.

Comment: Your indentation doesn't make your code really easier to read. Maybe let your IDE format your code for you (in Eclipse you can use `Source` menu and either `Format` or `Correct Indentation`).

Comment: You told us what it *doesn't* do.  What *does* it do instead?

Comment: @m0skit0 So because I am having the user enter in a number after every try each time it doesn't check each time just the original one entered?

Comment: @Pshemo we have to use Jgrasp and the way to format is very weird looking so I am slowly figuring out how to format

Comment: @WebCobra I took the liberty post formatted version of your code, hope you don't mind :)

Comment: @Pshemo I do not, lets me see how to correctly indent stuff since Jgrasp is really weird on that, thank you :)

Comment: @WebCobra See HyperZ answer for an example of what I mean.

Comment: You can easily format your code in eclipse using following shortcut : cmd + i (on mac). So first select the part you want to indent and then use the shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to do here ?

```
if (guess < 1 || guess > 10) {
}
```

You should try something like this :

```
public class Guess {
    static int guess, secretNumber =  (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args ) { 
        do {
            try {       
                guess = keyboard.nextInt();
                if (guess < 1 || guess >10){
                    System.out.println("Your guess is not in the corre try again.");
                }
                if(guess == secretNumber){
                    System.out.println("Your guess is correct. Congratulations!");
                }
                else if (guess < secretNumber){
                    System.out.println("Your guess is smaller than the secret number.");
                }
                else if (guess > secretNumber){ 
                    System.out.println("Your guess is greater than the secret number.");                                     
                }
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Not a valid integer");
            }
        } while (guess != secretNumber);
    }
}
```

EDIT : You have to put a piece of code which could maybe throw an exception, in the scope of the try block. It is state of the art to know which part of the code to put in the try block (not too much nor too less).

> in-between the try and catch you have your main code/calculations to
>   do and then you close it off and end with the catch to see if after
>   all that if what was entered was valid?

You could always catch the exceptions at top level like you're saying here, but in practice that's not the way to do it. Because when an exception occurs and you don't catch it there will be a process called stack unwinding.

It's really important to understand how stack unwinding works in order to understand what's happening.

You can find information about how this process works here : [Explanation of stack unwinding](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Exception_Handling). It explains stack unwinding in C++ but I expect it to be (exactly) the same in Java.

Comment: There are is no equals method for primitive types

Comment: Just move the try-catch inside the while, there's no need for a recursive call.

Comment: If I get how this works you need to start with the try block and the code you are evaluating in this case its `if (guess < 1 || guess >10)` along with the outputted message and in-between the try and catch you have your main code/calculations to do and then you close it off and end with the catch to see if after all that if what was entered was valid?

Comment: I edited the answer in order to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach, but using Exceptions.  Please, read [this page](http://www.functionx.com/java/Lesson15.htm) to understand how try/catch block works.

```
//import statements
import java.util.*;     //for scanner class


// class beginning
class  Guess {
public static void main(String[] args ) { 
//Declare variables area
int secretNumber, guess;

secretNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


// beginning message to user to explain the program
System.out.println("Welcome to my guess a number program!");
System.out.println("Please enter in a number to begin guess what the secret number is(1-10): ");

//Collect inputs from user or read in data here


//main code and calculations to do
do {


  System.out.println("Enter a guess (1-10): ");
  try {
    guess = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (guess < 1 || guess > 10){
      throw new Exception("Number must be  between 1 and 10");
    }else if(guess == secretNumber){
   throw new Exception("YOU WIN");
  }
  else if (guess < secretNumber){
   throw new Exception("NUMBER IS +");
  }
  else if (guess > secretNumber){
  throw new Exception("NUMBER IS -");
  }
} catch (InputMismatchException e)
{
  System.println("mustbeanumber");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
 System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}

} while (guess != secretNumber);


//End program message
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Hope you enjoyed using this program!");
}// end main method 


}// end class`
```

Comment: `IT's`?  What's that?

Comment: This isn't a good solution AFAICT.  It'll only try again once.

Comment: the line `guess = keyboard.nextInt();` is unreachable in several branches where it's placed

Comment: In fact, there is no need to do it.. it´ll be done at when "do"  starts again

Comment: Corrected and deleted the first `guess = keyboard.nextInt();`  before the try

Comment: Please format your code correctly. `System.out.println(e.getMessage())` <- Don't do this, you won't see the stacktrace that tells you exactly what happened. Also you don't need to catch Exception in this case (and in most cases).